# jQuery Tablesorter digit sort fail

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Running a digit sort descend on a hidden div that is numbered `1-73` and this is the result I get:

```
58,
47,
45-39,
15-10,
73-59,
57-48,
46,
38-21,
2,
10-16,
1,
9-3
```

What the heck??!!

EDIT - adding more details plus a realization. I forgot that this code was using a textExtraction, which I have used successfully in other areas but it is not working for some reason here.

The tablesorter code:

```
$("#mytable").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        1: { sorter: "digit" }
    },
    textExtraction: {
        1: function (node, table, cellIndex) { return $(node.childNodes[0]).find("div").text(); }
    },
    widgets: ["zebra"],
    sortList: [[1, 1]]
});
```

Then the cell I am trying to sort:

```
<td align=""center""><div class=""clsHide"">73</div><div>9/30/2016<br />10:16 PM</div></td>
```

If I take the date out of the cell, it sorts correctly. So it must be something to do with my textExtraction not working, but it is the same code I have used successfully in other areas so I am not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: provide a [mcve] if you want any help

Comment: Are you sorting those as strings? They look sorted alphabetically descending.

Comment: Apologies for such a poorly documented question. Added more details, hopefully someone can see what I am doing wrong

Comment: Are you using tablesorter v2.0.5? If so, the `textExtraction` function does not support targeting specific columns - see [this blog post](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#textExtraction), make sure to read the note.

Comment: I think maybe `return $(node).find("div").text();` is more likely to find your div.

Comment: Are the double double-quotes, for example, `<div class=""clsHide"">` just a typo?